# The link to share a document isn't valid

Tags: document, hyperlink, share

I have been sharing document links for years but now when I copy the link to share a document the link is no longer valid because there are extra characters on the end.

**Used to look like:**
https://company.sharepoint.com/Sales/Shipping%20Library/Lead%20Times/GH-%20%2004-12%20-%20LT.pdf

**Now looks like:**
https://company.sharepoint.com/Sales/Shipping%20Library/Lead%20Times/GH-%20%2004-12%20-%20LT.pdf?d=wc39ecc2480bf480da8ce4319bf12d8bc

Comment: what makes you think this is invalid? it has been this way in sharepoint online for a while btw

Comment: Eric Because when my users click the link it leads them to a 404.  The only way I can work around it is if I delete all items after the PDF.   I send several links a day and as of last week it's been working fine.

Comment: This only appears to be an issue with PDFs as SharePoint Online is trying to open the file in Office Web Apps and there is no corresponding app for pdfs. If you change your library to open files in client applications does it then work?

Comment: Sorry, lets try this again.  If I click on the document while in sp it opens in the browser as a pdf and I can copy the correct link to paste in a email to share with staff.  If I get the link from "Open Menu Dialog" in sp it shows the link with the extra digits on the end and I have to delete those extra digits for the link to work.